# Flex: browser manager's hidden frame is showing on page?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a flex application that uses BrowserManager for Deep Linking.

But whenever the # changes the new hash fragment gets appending to the bottom of the page. In IE it is inside a frame that says "Hidden frame for Browser History support." I didn't even know it worked that way. But anyways it is not supposed to be showing up visibly on the page but it is...anyone have any ideas what the problem is or how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...I copied the source from the template and put it into my page...somehow I missed this part when I copied it over:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="history/history.css" />
```

It works as expected now...thanks!